How do I show a value from a REST API in a Thymeleaf page
I must use a value read from an external REST API and put it in a Thymeleaf page.
@GetMapping("/api")
public String getIndirizzo(Model model) {
    String uri = "http://localhost:8081/api/byid/1";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resultString = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    
    model.addAttribute("attIndirizzo",resultString);

    return "index";
}

I want the read value to be formatted correctly without curly braces

That sounds like you need to parse the response (e.g. from JSON), instead of just trying to get it directly as a string. But you really need to provide a [mre].

In case you get JSON from API you may prepare POJO class or record mapping names and types from JSON. Then call restTemplate with NameOfMyPOJOClass.class. Pass result (the MyPOJOClass object) to model and use it in thymeleaf template.
